# CSS expand just on left

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have three cards. They are divided in two parts: the front and back. If the user wants to switch it, he has to click on the cards and the back appears rotating. For now it works fine.

I wanted to make an addition: when the back is showing, I'd like it to expand also to the right and to the left. I need this because I will insert a few tables at the back and I need space. This is ended halfway.

In fact, as you can see from **[THIS EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview)**, the back of the card expands only to left. Why? How can I fix?

```
     <div class="cards">
      <div class="riga">
        <div class="r2">
          <div class="r4">
            <div class="card-container manual-flip">
              <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                <div class="front">
                  <div class="cover">
                    <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="user">
                    <img src="img/img1.png" class="img-circle" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                      <p class="profession">Text</p>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Info
                                            </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                  <div class="header">
                    <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                            Back  
                                        </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="r4">
            <div class="card-container manual-flip">
              <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                <div class="front">
                  <div class="cover">
                    <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb.png" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="user">
                    <img src="img/img2.png" class="img-circle" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                      <p class="profession">Text</p>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                               Info
                                            </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                  <div class="header">
                    <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                            Back  
                                        </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="r4">
            <div class="card-container manual-flip">
              <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                <div class="front">
                  <div class="cover">
                    <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="user">
                    <img src="img/img3.png" class="img-circle" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                      <p class="profession">Text</p>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                      <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Info
                                            </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                  <div class="header">
                    <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="main">
                      <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                            Back  
                                        </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have constraint on your back card to align it with the left side of its container, so to the right when its rotated.

```
.front, .back {
    left: 0;
}
```

You should adapt this to center your overflowing card. You can do it with a `calc()` function.

```
.back {
    width: 900px;
    left: calc((100% - 900px) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Super! But I still have a problem: if you try your solution and try to rotate the card, you can see that the front of the card by side remains visible even if I write to the back of the current back card z-index: 32059123950123

Comment: This is a different question ;) You use `perspective` on `.card-container`, this create a stacking context for each card. If you do not resolve the stacking order, which comes last in the DOM will be on the top. So you have to add a `z-index` on the `.card-container` of your flipped cards.

Comment: I tried to give an ID for each .container giving a z-index different ... but the problem remains because so only the back of the card (one of three) will appear good, the other not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this: `.card-container.hover.manual-flip {z-index: 2;}`

Comment: It doesn't work putting z-index:2 on .card-container :/

Comment: `.card-container.hover.manual-flip {position: relative; z-index: 2;}` seems to work

Comment: my god i used wrong selector!! lol! Thank you very very much for you help!